# Check if image file exist

Tags: php

I want to check if a img file exist else i use a default img.

but the check i want to use to be sure the image file is there dosnt work.

I have the following code.

```
$filename = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/media/img/".$row['CatNaam'].".jpg";
        echo"  <img src=\"".$filename."\" alt=\"".$row['CatNaam']."\">";

        echo "filename";

        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            echo "The file $filename exists";
        } else {
            echo "The file $filename does not exist";
        }
```

the image is there i can see it, but it says that the image does not exist.
if i copy the response from echo filename the file is there.

EDIT:

i changed my code to

```
$filename = "/media/img/".$row['CatNaam'].".jpg";
        echo $filename;
        echo"  <img src=\"".$filename."\" alt=\"".$row['CatNaam']."\">";


         echo "<br> $filename <br>";
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            echo "The file $filename exists";
        } else {
            echo "The file $filename does not exist";
        }
```

I can still see the image but now i get a diffrent warning ( i gues this is better then before)

the warning says:

arning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/media/img/Badkraan.jpg) is not within the allowed path(s): (censored) in mydomain/public_html/ve/paginas/producten/zoek.php on line 71
The file /media/img/Badkraan.jpg does not exist

The filepermission is 755

Comment: What permissions do the image / containing folder have ?

Comment: See my answer. Get the base directory using dirname. Let's make an example: say you get something like: '/home/youruser/domain/public_html/scripts'. Then your directory will be that dir . '../media/img'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source : https://www.php.net/file_exists

```
<?php
    $filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "The file $filename exists";
    } else {
        echo "The file $filename does not exist";
    }
?>
```

**OR**

Source : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php

```
<?php
    var_dump(is_file('a_file.txt')) . "\n";
    var_dump(is_file('/usr/bin/')) . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$imgFile = "http://www.technew.in/uploads/image/samsung_galaxy_xpro_2_technew_in.jpg";
if (getimagesize($imgFile)) {
  echo "Valid image file";
} else {
  echo "Invalid image file or file not exist";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
$file = 'Your_file';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);

if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
   // does not exist
} else {
   // exist     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following things

- make sure `$filename` is properly validated
- it will only work when `allow_url_fopen` is activated in your PHP
  config
- make sure you have given permission for the image folder

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the file as the client sees it (http...). You need instead to check the actual file on the server's disk, i.e. if you are on linux something like:

```
if(file_exists($PATH_TO_FILES . '/' . $row['CatNaam'] . ".jpg")) ...
```

where $PATH_TO_FILES may be computed starting with something like: `dirname(__FILE__))`, which will give you the directory your current script sits.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `file_exists` does not work properly for files served over the http-protocol. At least it's like that in my case (even with `allow_url_fopen` set to `On`). I'm assuming the files are coming from a different server where you don't have direct access to the file system. Otherwise it would be easier to just use the full path to the file itself.

You could try it like this though. It's not that nice, but it should at least get the job done. You should be able to find some other examples on the php.net page for `file_exists`.

```
$filename = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/media/img/".$row['CatNaam'].".jpg";
echo"  <img src=\"".$filename."\" alt=\"".$row['CatNaam']."\">";
echo "filename";

$file_headers = @get_headers($filename);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
else {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
}
```

Comment: the files are on the same server as my website i a media dir with 755 (tryd 777 no difrence ) permissions

Comment: then it probably would be easier to use the absolute file path instead of the http-url.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and i solve it by giving the actual address ,it ant pretty but it is work for me :

1- first get the addrss for current location and put it in an array:

```
$pieces = explode("/", __FILE__);
```

2-change the address to fit the file you want :

```
array_pop($pieces);
```

3-finally put it together :

```
$final = implode("/", $pieces);
```

4- then put it in file exist function.

Answer (score 0):

$filename = "http://im.rediff.com/money/2011/jan/19sld3.jpg";

```
    $file_headers = @get_headers($filename);

    if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    //return false; 
    echo "file not found";
    }else {
    //return true;  
    echo "file found";

    }
```